# This is another number sequence puzzle!

Tags: number-sequence

Can you find the next number in the following sequence:

> 3, 6, 9, 8, 13, 20, 17, 14, 21, **?**

If you're operating differently you probably prefer to solve the following sequence:

> 2, 0, 0, 12, 35, 384, 135, 32, 315, **?**

---

**Hint 1**

> The missing numbers are not the same.

**Hint 2**

> Both sequences are finite

Comment: Thanks @Rubio. I've changed the puzzle and added a sequence I wanted to use as a hint later. Do you think this one's better or should I try it in the sandbox first?

Comment: This seems better now, yes; thanks for being open to feedback :)

Comment: Might be useful to someone: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m17pq62ero

Comment: Would it always be the same if it starts with the same number? Or could there be multiple sequences that start with 3, using this pattern?

Comment: This sequence is neither arithmetic or geometric??

Comment: It's been a long time, can we get another hint (possibly a strong one?) :)

Answer (score 1):

Observation 1)

> Split the sequence into $(3, 6, 9, 8)$ - three increasing one decreasing, $(13, 20, 17, 14)$ - two increasing two decreasing and $(21, ?, \cdots,\cdots)$ - one increasing three decreasing. So the question mark must be less than $21$.

Observation 2)

> The consecutive differences are $3,3,3,1,5,7,3,3,7$. They are no more than $10$ and $1$ occurs once, $3$ occurs five times, $5$ occurs once and $7$ occurs twice. Except $7$, the number of occurrences are odd, so the difference between $21$ and the question mark is either $7$ or $17$. If it is the latter, that introduces an extra $1$ which breaks the odd rule.

Solution

> Therefore, the missing number is $21-7=14$.